# Increasing the titlebar and other elements' width to cover the whole JQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `JQuery` dialog box that displays a table on button click.

I need:
1. The titlebar of the dialog box to cover the entire width of the dialog box. Currently, the title bar has some of the dialog box peeking out on all sides.
2. There is a row in the table. The row should cover the entire dialog box. How do I remove the margins on either side of the row? Setting margin, padding to 0 does not help.

HTML:

```
<button id="x">Click</button>
<!-- The part below is for the recorder dialog. -->
<div id="dialog-form-speakingPractice" class="ui-helper-hidden">
    <table id="recordTable" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" id="word2Record">'Word'</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#x").click(function () {
        alert("Button clicked");
        startRecorderDialog();
        $("#dialog-form-speakingPractice").dialog("open");
    });

    function startRecorderDialog() {
        $("#dialog-form-speakingPractice").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            dialogClass: 'recorderDialogCSS',
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            }
        });
        $("#dialog-form-speakingPractice").dialog('option', 'title', 'Listen to Word');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    background: transparent;
}
.recorderDialogCSS.ui-dialog {
    color: black;
    background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}
.recorderDialogCSS .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(0, 83, 146);
    text-align: center;
    border: 0px;
}
#recordTable {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#recordTable td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#word2Record {
    background: rgb(133, 184, 56);
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I also have a [JFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/sriramshankar/vLSLn/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLSLn/1/). Changes made:

```
.recorderDialogCSS.ui-dialog {
    ...
    padding: 0;
}
#dialog-form-speakingPractice {
    padding:0;
}
#recordTable {
    ...
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your **CSS** :

```
.ui-dialog{
   padding:0px; !important
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete or comment the padding in the two following classes

```
.ui-dialog {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*padding: .2em;*/
    outline: 0;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    /*padding: .5em 1em;*/
    background: none;
    overflow: auto;
}
```